# Optimized way to update parent object

Tags: apex, dml, performance

What is the most optimized way to update every parent object inside a list?

For example:

```
List<Asset> aList =
[
    SELECT
        Account.Name
    FROM
        Asset
    WHERE
        Status__c = 'Expired'
];

a[0].Account.Name = 'Testing 1-2 Test';

update a;
```

The Account name will not be updated. How can I achieve this easily and efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update an object only the fields directly on the object are processed.  You'll need to do a specific update on the account.  If it's possible to see the same accountId twice you'll need to do a map to ensure you aren't inserting duplicates.  Otherwise a list will do.

```
List<Asset> assets = [select accountId from Asset where Status__c = 'Expired'];
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Asset asset : assets) {
  accountMap.put(
      asset.accountId
    , new Account(
        id = asset.accountId
      , name = 'New Name'
    )
  );
}
update accountMap.values();
```

Comment: I tried your solution previously, but I received a `Duplicate id` error since I'm trying to save a record with an existing ID.

Comment: you want a map then, updating the answer

Comment: I originally didn't think this would work because I assumed the Id field was uneditable. It recently changed with Spring '13 though - http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Spring13/Setting+ID++Fields+for+Updates so this would definitely work.

Comment: It's only settable during object construction, otherwise it's uneditable.

Comment: @jpmonette did this work for you?

Comment: @Ralph Yes it did.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ralph's solution which works great, one other mechanism you can use to perform this operation is to leverage the [`sObject.getSObject()` method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) on the `sObject`s returned by the query.

This will let you retrieve the `Account` object (parent) from each of your `Asset` objects. These accounts can then be collected into a unique list, modified as necessary and updated.

This method is typically used when performing [dynamic DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_dml.htm), but has some use here as well.

```
List<Asset> assets = [SELECT Id
                            , Account.Name
                            , Account.Id
                        FROM Asset
                        WHERE Status__c = 'Expired'];

Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();

for (Asset a : assets) {
    if (!accountsToUpdate.containsKey(a.Account.Id)) {
        // cast the sObject back to an Account type
        Account acct = (Account)a.getSObject('Account');

        // modify a field
        acct.Name = 'Some new account name';

        // add to the map
        accountsToUpdate.put(a.Account.Id, acct);

    } else {
        system.debug('Account already in the map.');
    }
}

// system.debug(accountsToUpdate);

system.savepoint sp1 = database.setsavepoint();    
update accountsToUpdate.values();    
database.rollback(sp1);
```

Comment: Cool approach, hadn't thought of using that, it's very clean

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use the dynamic DML method.  You can just grap it directly.  Account acct = a.Account;

Answer (score 0):

**Why not go something like this:**

1. Get the account Name you want to change
2. Grab the account matching on that name
3. update Account

**Below is some pseudo code:**

```
String name = a[0].Account.Name;
Account acc = [Select id, name from Account where name =: name];
acc.name = 'abc';
update acc;
```

Comment: Because it will require a bunch of SOQL request when I'll have +1000 records to check. I could probably build a list with every AccountId from my Asset List and then do a single SOQL request using a `WHERE Id IN :idList`, but it will require at least 1 loop + 1 SOQL request. I'm wondering if there's a easier way.

I know I can do something like `update a.Account` to update the Account when we only request a single record, but not with a list (or I don't know how!)